# How to avoid Using temporary; Using filesort on MySql Query

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, mariadb

Currently I am facing a rather slow query on a website, which also slows down the server on more traffic. How can I rewrite the query or what index can I write to avoid "Using temporary; Using filesort"? Without "order by" everything works fast, but without the wanted result/order.

```
SELECT cams.name, models.gender, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, models.birthdate, CURRENT_DATE) AS age, lcs.viewers
FROM cams
         LEFT JOIN cam_tags ON cams.id = cam_tags.cam_id
         INNER JOIN tags ON cam_tags.tag_id = tags.id
         LEFT JOIN model_cams ON cams.id = model_cams.cam_id
         LEFT JOIN models ON model_cams.model_id = models.id
         LEFT JOIN latest_cam_stats lcs ON cams.id = lcs.cam_id
WHERE tags.name = '?'
ORDER BY lcs.time_stamp_id DESC, lcs.viewers DESC
LIMIT 24 OFFSET 96;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | tags | NULL | const | PRIMARY,tags_name_uindex | tags_name_uindex | 766 | const | 1 | 100 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | cam_tags | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,cam_tags_cams_id_fk,cam_tags_tags_id_fk | cam_tags_tags_id_fk | 4 | const | 75565047 | 100 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | cams | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | cam_tags.cam_id | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | model_cams | NULL | eq_ref | model_platforms_platforms_id_fk | model_platforms_platforms_id_fk | 4 | cam_tags.cam_id | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | models | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | model_cams.model_id | 1 | 100 | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | lcs | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,latest_cam_stats_cam_id_time_stamp_id_viewers_index | PRIMARY | 4 | cam_tags.cam_id | 1 | 100 | NULL |

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases where it is effectively impossible to avoid "using temporary, using filesort".

"Filesort" does not necessarily involve a "file"; it is often done in RAM.  Hence performance may not be noticeably hurt.

That said, I will assume your *real* question is "How can this query be sped up?".

Most of the tables are accessed via `PRIMARY` or "eq_ref" -- all good.  But the second table involves touching an estimated 75M rows!  Often that happens as the first table, not second.  Hmmmm.

Sounds like `cam_tags` is a many-to-many mapping table?  And it does not have any index *starting* with `name`?  See this for proper indexes for such a table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Since the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` reference more than one table, it is essentially impossible to avoid "using temporary, using filesort".

Worse than that, it needs to find all the ones with "name='?'", sort the list, skip 96 rows, and only finally deliver 24.